# PHP get_browser returns different results on WAMP and linux server

Tags: php

When using the get_browser function in PHP on:

- Linux server - works perfectly.
- WAMP server - returns "Default Browser"

I have just downloaded the latest browscap.in file.

My user_agent is: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1`

WAMP:

```
Array
(
    [browser_name_regex] => §^.*$§
    [browser_name_pattern] => *
    [browser] => Default Browser
    [version] => 0
    [majorver] => 0
    [minorver] => 0
    [platform] => unknown
    [alpha] => 
    [beta] => 
    [win16] => 
    [win32] => 
    [win64] => 
    [frames] => 
    [iframes] => 
    [tables] => 
    [cookies] => 
    [backgroundsounds] => 
    [javascript] => 
    [vbscript] => 
    [javaapplets] => 
    [activexcontrols] => 
    [isbanned] => 
    [ismobiledevice] => 
    [issyndicationreader] => 
    [crawler] => 
    [cssversion] => 0
    [aolversion] => 0
)
```

Server:

```
Array
(
    [browser_name_regex] => �^mozilla/5\.0 \(.*windows nt 6\.1.*wow64.*rv:.*\) gecko/.* firefox/9\..*$�
    [browser_name_pattern] => Mozilla/5.0 (*Windows NT 6.1*WOW64*rv:*) Gecko/* Firefox/9.*
    [parent] => Firefox 9.0
    [platform] => Win7
    [win32] => 
    [win64] => 1
    [browser] => Firefox
    [version] => 9.0
    [majorver] => 9
    [frames] => 1
    [iframes] => 1
    [tables] => 1
    [cookies] => 1
    [javascript] => 1
    [javaapplets] => 1
    [cssversion] => 3
    [minorver] => 0
    [alpha] => 
    [beta] => 
    [win16] => 
    [backgroundsounds] => 
    [vbscript] => 
    [activexcontrols] => 
    [isbanned] => 
    [ismobiledevice] => 
    [issyndicationreader] => 
    [crawler] => 
    [aolversion] => 0
)
```

QUESTION: How do I fix this issue in WAMP so that it behaviours like the linux server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use this "Standalone replacement for php's native get_browser() function"
https://github.com/garetjax/phpbrowscap

This library is suggested to be used in the [Browsercap page](http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads.asp)

Here is a list of the features:

- Fast
- Standalone
- Even faster parsing many user agents
- Fully get_browser() compatible
- Often faster and more accurate than get_browser()
- Fully PHP configuration independent
- User agent auto-detection
- Returns object or array
- Parsed .ini file cached directly into PHP arrays
- Accepts any .ini file (even ASP and lite versions)
- Auto updated browscap.ini file and cache from remote server with version checking
- Configurable remote update server
- Fully configurable (since 0.2)
- PHP4 and PHP5 compatible (PHP4 version deprecated)
- Released under the MIT License

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your `php.ini` file didn't contain path to `browscap` ini file.

Look if there present this setting:

```
[browscap]
browscap = /path/to/your/php_browscap.ini
```